My 2d godot player doesn't identify the ground
I want to define when the player touches the ground, some things happen, but it always identifies that it doesn't come into contact with the ground.
My version of Godot is 4.2.2.
This is my code:
extends CharacterBody2D
var dash = 300.0
var speed = 150.0
var jumpPower = -350.0
var jumpMax = 2
var jumpCount = 0

func _process(delta):
 moviment(delta)
 attack()
 print(is_on_floor())
 move_and_slide()

var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")
func _physics_process(delta):

 move_and_collide(Vector2(0, 1))
 velocity.y += gravity * delta
 var motion = velocity * delta
 move_and_collide(motion)
func moviment(delta)
    var direction = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
if direction != 0:

    $Anim.play("Walk")
    if direction > 0:
        $Anim.flip_h = false
        velocity.x += speed * delta
        velocity.x = clamp(speed, 100.0, speed)
    elif direction < 0:
        $Anim.flip_h = true
        velocity.x -= speed * delta
        velocity.x = clamp(-speed, 100.0, -speed)
else:

    velocity.x = 0
    $Anim.play("Idle")
jump()

func jump():

if is_on_floor() and jumpCount != 0:
    jumpCount = 0
if jumpCount<jumpMax:
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("move_up"):
        jumpCount += 1
        $Anim.play("Jump")
        velocity.y = jumpPower


This video might help

First of all, your code is sort of unreadable and I recommend fixing it <3
But to answer your question, your code should not even compile as it has syntax errors. Additionally to indentiations being all over the place, you have this syntax error:
func moviment(delta)

Missing a colon here
func movement(delta):


Seems that you are using move_and_collide to move your character. I think is_on_floor might only work when combined with move_and_slide: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_characterbody2d.html
If you want to use move_and_collide, you might have to implement ground detection.

Your move_and_slide function should be called in _physics_process NOT _process.
Additionally, the is_on_floor function needs to be called after move_and_slide. If you don't do this, collisions won't be updated correctly.
Check to see if your CharacterBody2D node has the correct collision shapes for the floor. Also, make sure your layer ordering is correct.
